# Xcode won't generate bitcode section

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, bitcode

im using xcode 13.2.1, MacOs Monterey version 12.2 (M1).
Im trying to compile my app with bitcode using xcode.
I have Bitcode-Enable = yes in **both** project and target.
I checked the build log and I have no warning stating I am using a framework/library that isn't compiled with bitcode so that's not the issue.

I archived the app and I also made sure to check the `rebuild with bitcode` option.
When I run the command `otool -l my-cool-app } | grep LLVM` it shows nothing (No bitcode section).  What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

forgot to update, apparently Bitcode-Enable = yes is not enough.
you need to specify the correct flag to compile the bitcode.

this is the command line I used:
xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" -target "${PROJECT_NAME}"

Comment: You should be able to update your question to include additional information, instead of posting a separate amendment as an "answer"